# Android how to encrypt/decrypt database

Tags: android, database, encryption

I want to encrypt/decrypt android database and for that I looked into SQLCipher, and it works if database is created using SQLCipher only. But in my case I have database created using Oracle Mobile Server, so what can be the solution to encrypt/decrypt already created database.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Only with Oracle Mobile Server and your key (or whatever it uses) otherwise your enrcyption wouldn't be that good.

Comment: Is there any help document available from oracle mobile server to encrypt database?

Comment: look here http://www.oracle.com/us/products/database/database-mobile-server/overview/index.html under Benefits.